# Ambiguous column name when doing a JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've got some troubles when doing a join in my statement

This one is OK

```
select [db_id], COUNT(db_id) AS total
FROM [dbauditor_repo].[dbo].[dbauditor_repo_events]
GROUP BY [db_id]
ORDER BY total DESC
```

But I'm getting an error when doing the join (Ambiguous column name 'db_id'.)

```
SELECT [db_name], [db_id], COUNT(db_id) AS total
FROM [dbauditor_repo].[dbo].[dbauditor_repo_events] JOIN [dbauditor_repo].[dbo].[dbauditor_repo_warehouse]
ON ([dbauditor_repo].[dbo].[dbauditor_repo_events].[db_id] = [dbauditor_repo].[dbo].[dbauditor_repo_warehouse].[db_id])
WHERE [db_type] = 'mysql'
GROUP BY [db_id]
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 5):

Just get in the habit of using table aliases for all column references.  That will prevent such errors and other unexpected problems.  The best practice is to use table abbreviations.  Here is an example:

```
SELECT rw.[db_name], re.[db_id], COUNT(re.db_id) AS total
FROM [dbauditor_repo].[dbo].[dbauditor_repo_events] re JOIN
     [dbauditor_repo].[dbo].[dbauditor_repo_warehouse] rw
     ON re.[db_id] = rw.[db_id])
WHERE rw.[db_type] = 'mysql'
GROUP BY rw.[db_name], re.[db_id]
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

Of course, I have to guess which tables the columns come from.  You should fix the query so they come from the right tables.

As a bonus, when using table aliases, queries are easier to write and to read.

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 37
Column 'dbauditor_repo.dbo.dbauditor_repo_warehouse.db_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Phil . . . Of course.  You are not using MySQL, so all the non-aggregated columns in the `select` need to go into the `group by`.  I wonder if I was thrown off by the `where` clause.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use fully qualified name when joining tables and the column exist in more than one table.

Try:

```
SELECT [dbauditor_repo_events].[db_id]
```

You also need to include the column `db_name` in the `GROUP BY` clause as this column is not being aggregated.

```
GROUP BY [dbauditor_repo_events].[db_id], [db_name]
```

Comment: I'm getting Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
Column 'dbauditor_repo.dbo.dbauditor_repo_warehouse.db_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
Ambiguous column name 'db_id'.

Comment: @Phil You need to include the column `db_name` in the `GROUP BY` clause as this column is not being aggregated

Answer (score 1):

It's in your select and group by:

```
SELECT [db_name], [dbauditor_repo_events].[db_id], COUNT([dbauditor_repo_events].db_id) AS total
FROM [dbauditor_repo].[dbo].[dbauditor_repo_events] JOIN [dbauditor_repo].[dbo].[dbauditor_repo_warehouse]
ON ([dbauditor_repo].[dbo].[dbauditor_repo_events].[db_id] = [dbauditor_repo].[dbo].[dbauditor_repo_warehouse].[db_id])
WHERE [db_type] = 'mysql'
GROUP BY [dbauditor_repo_events].[db_id]
ORDER BY total DESC
```

You should maybe consider aliasing your tables in the query for readability,e.g.:

```
SELECT [db_name], e.[db_id], COUNT(e.db_id) AS total
FROM [dbauditor_repo].[dbo].[dbauditor_repo_events] as e
JOIN [dbauditor_repo].[dbo].[dbauditor_repo_warehouse] as w
ON (e.[db_id] = w.[db_id])
WHERE [db_type] = 'mysql'
GROUP BY e.[db_id]
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Comment: Getting: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 29
Column 'dbauditor_repo.dbo.dbauditor_repo_warehouse.db_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

It is because:

```
[dbauditor_repo].[dbo].[dbauditor_repo_events]
```

and

```
[dbauditor_repo].[dbo].[dbauditor_repo_warehouse]
```

have the same column name db_id. The Query does not know which table's db_id to be used. Hence this error.

**Solution:**

Use `TableName.FieldName` or `TableAliasName.FieldName` to avoid this error. Change your Query as:

```
SELECT [db_name], 
       TAB1.[db_id] , 
       COUNT(TAB1.db_id) AS total
FROM 
    [dbauditor_repo].[dbo].[dbauditor_repo_events] AS TAB1
JOIN
    [dbauditor_repo].[dbo].[dbauditor_repo_warehouse] AS TAB2
ON 
    (TAB1.[db_id] = TAB2.[db_id])
WHERE [db_type] = 'mysql'

GROUP BY [db_name],[TAB1.db_id]

ORDER BY total DESC
```

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 46
Column 'dbauditor_repo.dbo.dbauditor_repo_warehouse.db_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Phil: Refer my current query. Your Group by should be `GROUP BY [db_name],[TAB1.db_id]`